# Visual Studio Code / and in Terminal - [-Wc++11-extensions] Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

This question has been asked a couple times and I followed the recommendations but I still have the problem. Here is the error:

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void test()
{

int v[]={0,1,2,3};

for(auto x:v)
    cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{

}
```

Error:

```
1p7.cpp:10:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
    ^
1p7.cpp:10:11: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
for(auto x:v)
          ^
2 warnings generated.
```

I've changed the settings:

C_Cpp › Default: Cpp Standard to c++11

And it is still not working. I don't want this to work just for this code but in general so running something like

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp
```

doesn't do much for me. It probably has something to do with the compiler but I've changed the compiler as well. I just reinstalled VS code and the C++ package. Still is not working. I tried this also via terminal and it shows the same two warnings without running g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Are you really using the full Visual Studio IDE, or the Visual Studio Code editor?

Comment: That `g++` command you show, which "doesn't do much for [you]", what *does* it do for you? What happens when you run that command? What errors do you get?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp` compiles the file `test.cpp` and produces executable file `a.out` in the same directory where it was called.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm using the Visual Studio Code editor as I wrote. Should I be using the IDE?

Comment: @mikanim What does `g++ --version` output for you?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just added an edit to show it.

Comment: I might also add that running this code via terminal also shows the same two warnings.